# Why is value comparison in hashtable returning false even when the values are the same?

Tags: c#, hashtable

In the following code, I am trying to check if two strings are anagrams. To that, I am counting the characters in the two strings in a hash table by storing the unique characters as key and its count in the string as values. At the end, when I go to check if each of the character have the same count, I get a false output, see the line marked as "PROBLEM" in the code. But when I convert the values in that line to string, the code works fine. What am I missing?

```
    static bool AreAnagrams(string input1, string input2)
    {
        Hashtable uniqueChars1 = new Hashtable();
        Hashtable uniqueChars2 = new Hashtable();

        // Go through first string and create a hash table of characters 
        AddToHashTable(input1, ref uniqueChars1);
        // Go through second string and create a second hash table of characters
        AddToHashTable(input2, ref uniqueChars2);

        // For each unique character, if the count from both hash tables are the same, they are anagrams
        if (uniqueChars1.Keys.Count != uniqueChars2.Keys.Count)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (object key in uniqueChars1.Keys)
            {
                if (uniqueChars1[key] != uniqueChars2[key]) // ***PROBLEM HERE***
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    static void AddToHashTable(string input, ref Hashtable uniqueChars)
    {
        foreach (char c in input)
        {

            if (!uniqueChars.ContainsKey(c))
            {
                uniqueChars.Add(c, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                int charCount = Convert.ToInt32(uniqueChars[c]);
                charCount++;
                uniqueChars[c] = charCount;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Hashtable` class is not generic; it just contains `Object`s, not a specific type.

When you do this:

```
if (uniqueChars1[key] != uniqueChars2[key])
```

the compile-time type of `uniqueChars[key]` is `Object`, not `Int32`. So you're using the `Object` implementation of the inequality operator, which just compares references. Since `Int32` is a value type, and the indexer returns an object, the value is [boxed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx); and since you're boxing two values, you get two distinct object instances, so reference equality always returns false.

You have several options:

- use a `Dictionary<char, int>`, which is the generic equivalent of `Hashtable`
- cast the values to `int` before comparison:

  ```
  if ((int)uniqueChars1[key] != (int)uniqueChars2[key])
  ```
- use the `Equals` method to compare values:

  ```
  if (!uniqueChars1[key].Equals(uniqueChars2[key]))
  ```

Unless you're still using .NET 1.x, I strongly advise you to use generic collections everywhere you can. They're safer, more intuitive, and have better performance for value types.

---

**Side note** (unrelated to your problem): you don't need to pass the `Hashtable` by reference to `AddToHashTable`; the code would work exactly the same way without the `ref` modifier, because `Hashtable` is a reference type, so it's always a reference that is passed anyway. The `ref` modifier would only be useful if you were assigning something else to the `uniqueChars` parameter, or if you were passing a value type and mutating its state (which is usually consider a bad thing). I suggest you read [Jon Skeet's great article about value types, reference types, and parameter passing](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html).

Comment: You mean `Hashtable` is a reference type right? not the method `AddToHashTable`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the fact that `!=` will compare reference equality on two objects. `uniqueCharsX[key]` returns a int boxed inside a object, while you have the same int being returned from both hashtables the box they are being returned in is not the same box so you get a incorrect value.

Either use a strongly typed `Dictionary<char, int>` instead of a hashtable or use `!uniqueChars1[key].Equals(uniqueChars2[key])` instead of `uniqueChars1[key] != uniqueChars2[key]` which will unbox the int and compare on the value instead (I highly recommend you use the Dictionary.)